# Postgres group by template variable in Grafana

Tags: postgresql, grafana

I have a table that I want to do a group by using a template variable. If I use the column names on their own everything works fine, but when I try to add the template variable I get `db query error: pq: non-integer constant in GROUP BY`. The template variable is just the name of the column. Is there a way to use them? I read in a post from 2017 that they havent implemented it, and thought that maybe by now they had a fix.

working example

```
SELECT 
column_A,
SUM(column_B),
SUM(column_C)
FROM my_table

GROUP BY column_A
```

non working example

```
SELECT 
column_A,
SUM(column_B),
SUM(column_C)
FROM my_table

GROUP BY $my_template_variable
```

the template variable is just the string column_A

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by environmental variable? Was this supposed to be [environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) (like from operation system)? If so - no, this is not supported. Use [dashboard variables](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/dashboards/variables/) (also know as template variables)

Comment: @markalex sorry I meant dashboard/template variables and I have been trying to use it and get the error seen above

Comment: Probably something to do with quotation. Please show final query sent to postgre (in menu of panel: Inspect > Query, and there press refresh). Also, what type is your variable: textbox, custom, query, etc? And is it multi-select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what caused it to work. Possible that a column had a similar name in two tables and I was trying to group by it. So what ended up fixing it was changing `GROUP BY $my_template_variable` to `GROUP BY main_table.$my_template_variable`